# How to switch from ascii postgresql database to utf8 on docker?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, utf-8

I'm having an issue in my docker bash, i'm trying to create a super user on django using `docker-compose exec web python manage.py createsuperuser` but I have this error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 68, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 118, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 431, in exec_command
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1236, in call_docker
  File "distutils\spawn.py", line 220, in find_executable
  File "ntpath.py", line 85, in join
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

---

I think it's because my database Postgresql is encoded in 'ascii' instead of utf-8, what are the commands to encode my psql database to `utf-8`?

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /config
ADD /config/requirements.pip /config/
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.pip
RUN mkdir /src;
WORKDIR /src
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: NGINX
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static
      - /media:/media
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: DJANGO
    command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn oqtor.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - /static:/static
      - /media:/media
    expose:
      - "8000"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: PSQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tilde character ("é" ) in your docker-compose.yml

---

Edit. Probably you have accents in the involved paths and probably you are facing some python bug in your host. You can try updating python in the host (docker-compose is made in python).

Comment: Probably you have accents in the involved paths? Where the docker compose is placed.

Comment: Yes I found a path with an accent...Thank you